# How do I use the edge version of Sunspot direct from Github instead of via Rubygems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, github, sunspot

In order to overcome a bug with solr, I need to run a newer version than the one included in the Rubygems version of Sunspot. I noticed on Github that there has been a very [recent commit](https://github.com/mrcsparker/sunspot/commit/f64afd0fda4d0cd0a5ac203cf3711368de7a36bc) which includes a newer version of Solr.

How do I configure my Gemfile to pull straight from the repo instead of from RubyGems. Currently I have the following;

```
gem 'sunspot'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_test'
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
  gem 'progress_bar'
end
```

If I simply add the repo to the sunspot gem line, everything falls apart when I run bundle. As the sunspot_solr gem is [within the sunspot repo](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/tree/master/sunspot_solr), I don't know the line I should use to grab that from the repo.

Thanks,
Graeme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it! The answer is to point to the main repo on github and use require where appropriate to narrow it down to the relevant sub-section.

The edited Gemfile is as follows;

```
gem 'sunspot', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require =>  "sunspot_rails"
gem 'sunspot_test'
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_solr"
  gem 'progress_bar'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ruby developer, but here is a walkthrough on [Installing Gems from Git](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/gitgem.htm) that may be helpful.